# Can I pass a parameter directly to a .js file, and how do I get the value

Tags: javascript, dom, parameters

I want to pass a parameter to some javascript using a single line of code, like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="courselist.js?subj=MATH" type="text/javascript" />
```

Inside the javascript file, how can I get the value of the parameter "subj"?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's as far only possible by accessing "own" `<script>` element in the HTML DOM and parse the `src` attribute.

Long story short, here's a nice article with detailed explanations and code samples: http://feather.elektrum.org/book/src.html

Answer (score 17):

Why not just create the variable in inside a script tag before including the javascript file?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var subj = "MATH";
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="courselist.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: This is how I have done it now, I was trying to keep the code to a single line.  This line of code is going to be used to include some dynamic content through our CMS.

Comment: Well, if you REALLY want it on a single line, you could just remove the line breaks ;)

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get something like this to work is to have the server serving up a dynamically generated javascript file where it has something like this on the server:

```
if(Parameters["subj"]=="MATH"){
  jsfile="var subj='MATH'; "+jsfile;
}...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Javascript file would be aware of the parameter that is passed to it. If that address goes to some sort of server-side script (NOT just a static Javascript file), then you may be able to do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

When a script, loaded from a script src file is interpreted, its related script element exists in the document.

Don't worry about which file is which- look at **every** script element for an url with a query string.