# Get variable in external js file from php

Tags: php, javascript, html, variables, external

I am trying to send variable from php to external js file without any success...

### for example :

```
<?php
$test = 'hello world!';
?>
<script src="external.js">
```

---

### now... this is the external.js file :

```
alert("<?php echo $test?>");
alert("<?=$test?>");
```

---

I tried couple of other methods but none of them is working for me :/

any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with this:

File: test.php

```
<?php 
$test = 'hello world!'; 
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>var test = '<?php echo $test; ?>';</script>
<script src="external.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

File: external.js:

```
alert(test);
```

I got the idea reading this article:
[Can I pass a parameter directly to a .js file, and how do I get the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145650/can-i-pass-a-parameter-directly-to-a-js-file-and-how-do-i-get-the-value)

Comment: OMG so simple but it works :) ! Thanks a lot man !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't include php code in a js file, 
include all code in the same file

```
<?php
$test = 'hello world!';
?>
<script>
    alert("<?php echo $test;?>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should Create a quick little session for this...
here it is the code

***Your PHP File***********

```
<?php
$test = "Hello World";
session_start();
$_SESSION['test']=$test;
?>
```

And Here it is my humble suggetion..
don't use .js extension just create file with .php and use  tags to add javascript

***external file containing javascript with .php extension******

```
<!-----------Your script-------------->
<script>
alert(<?php echo $test; ?>)
</script>
```

Sorry if you don't like my suggetion....
and don't forget vote + if you like...

Comment: I know that this is work as internal script within the php file but I do need to use external file and save it as php file is not the best solution for me because I use javascript compression so I must stay in external js file. Maybe there is a solution via get method for example :

    <script src="external.js?sendmessage=hello-world">

Any Idea ?