# How to check which HTML is being used from JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, html, file

I am using one JavaScript file for multiple HTML files, but I don't want a certain part of the JavaScript file to be used for one of the HTML files. How do I check which HTML file is being used?

Comment: window.location - welcome to SO. Please visit [help] to see how to ask questions

Answer (score 1):

you can use window.location to get the url and parse the result and handle that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location` to get the current URL.

But, really, I think a better approach would be to have some argument or setting to activate or disable functionality. That would give you more flexibility in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to pass parameters to the javascript. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3145654/2213940)
you can also use globals, but parameters are cleaner and safer.